# setState not recognized in flutter Androidstudio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

**I have seen answers on the internet but in all of them the OP has used StatelessWidget rather than StatefulWidget. i have used a StatefulWidget but still setState() is not recognized**

Kindly refer to line 43 of the code.

Hi! i am trying to learn flutter and was making a Weather forecast app as a project
in order to achieve that i was following a tutorial on youtube the youtuber had no error as he was working in visual studio code, I on the other am using Android studio

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() => runApp(
 MaterialApp(
 title: "Weather App",
 home: Home(),
 )//MaterialApp
 );

class Home extends StatefulWidget {


 @override
 State<StatefulWidget>createState()
 {
  return _HomeState();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // TODO: implement build

   throw UnimplementedError();
   }
  }

class _HomeState extends State<Home>{

  var temp;
  var description;
  var currently;
  var humidity;
  var windSpeed;

  Future getWeather() async {
   http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Delhi&APPID=4570e05ab53aad5b3893831a809ee608");
var results = jsonDecode(response.body);

  setState((){                                      //<- THIS IS NOT RECOGNIZED
    this.temp = results['main']['temp'];
    this.description = results['weather'][0]['description'];
    this.currently = results['weather'][0]['main'];
    this.humidity = results['main']['humidity'];
    this.windSpeed = results['main']['speed'];
  })
  }
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center ,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
              child: Text(
                "Currently in Boston",
                style: TextStyle
                  (
                  color:  Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                  ),
              ),

            ),
            Text(
              "52\u00B0",
              style:TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize:40.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                child: Text(
                    "Rain",
                    style: TextStyle
                      (
                        color:  Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                    ),
                ),

            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child:ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.temperatureHalf),
              title: Text("Temprature"),
              trailing: Text("52\u00B0"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.cloud),
              title: Text("Weather"),
              trailing: Text("Weather"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.sun),
              title: Text("Humidity"),
              trailing: Text("12"),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.wind),
              title: Text("Wind Speed"),
              trailing: Text("12"),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ))
    ],
  ),
);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `;` missing at the end of your ***setState((){...})***`;`

I think you should use `Uri.parse()`:

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Delhi&APPID=4570e05ab53aad5b3893831a809ee608"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call your function getWeather, for example in the init state method.

```
@override
  initState() {
    getWeather();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! was missing a semicolon.